# Drag and Drop not working using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

I used the following code, it is executing without any error. But drag and drop action didn't happen.

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" + "var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n"
            + "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" + "event.dataTransfer = {\n" + "data: {},\n"
            + "setData: function (key, value) {\n" + "this.data[key] = value;\n" + "},\n"
            + "getData: function (key) {\n" + "return this.data[key];\n" + "}\n" + "};\n" + "return event;\n"
            + "}\n" + "\n" + "function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n"
            + "if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" + "event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" + "}\n"
            + "if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n"
            + "} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" + "element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" + "}\n"
            + "}\n" + "\n" + "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n"
            + "var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" + "dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n"
            + "var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n"
            + "dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n"
            + "var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n"
            + "dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" + "}\n" + "\n"
            + "var source = arguments[0];\n" + "var destination = arguments[1];\n"
            + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);", from1, to1);
```

Comment: Wow. It doesn't look that straightforward. Have you tried anything like this? https://www.guru99.com/drag-drop-selenium.html If yes, why did you choose this JavaScript solution?

Comment: Yes, i tried but drag and drop didn't work. i tried lots of solution but got same results only.

Comment: I expect `from1` and `to1` are `WebElement`. Are they correctly located? Log `element.getRect().getX()`, `element.getRect.getY()`, `element.getLocation().getX()` and `element.getLocation().getY()` of both to see more.